# How permanently delete branch in git pushed with `--allow-unrelated-histories`

Tags: git, git-merge

My problem:
I accidentally merge `master` branch from git repository (let's call it `repo1`) to another git repository (let's call it `repo2`) using `--allow-unrelated-histories` flag.

I was able restore original `repo2` `master` branch, but I have about 300  detached commits from `repo1` in `repo2`.

Is it possible to somehow remove them?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing fundamentally wrong with having some other repository's commits lingering in your own repository, but if you want to get rid of them, you must do two things:

1. Get rid of any *names* that *find* them.  With the names gone, you won't *see* them any more.

   This part is normally really easy: if you have a remote you added with `git remote add` that is incorrect, just run `git remote remove` on that same remote.  That will delete all the remote-tracking names.

   You can stop here if disk space etc are not a concern.
2. Actually force a garbage collection, usually after also getting rid of any hidden (normally-invisible) names for the commits from the other repository.

   This involves clearing out any reflog entries that might refer to the other repository.  The simplest method is to flush out all reflogs, although this means throwing out all safety memory.  If you know what you are doing you can individually discard particular reflog entries with `git reflog delete`; see [the documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-reflog.html) for details.

   Once the hidden names are gone, a simple `git gc` will discard the extra objects.

You can just wait a month or so instead of attempting step 2; after 30 days, by default, these reflog entries expire on their own.